# Row sum as am extra column in the table in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to make a descriptive table. I first calculate number of observations per group and per year. Then, I would like to add another column with the sum of the observations per year.

How would I do this without having to use a merge function?

```
year <- rep(2014:2015, length.out = 10000)
group <- sample(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
value <- sample(10000, replace = T)

dta <- data.frame(year = year, group = group, value = value)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dta1 <- dta %>%
  group_by(year, group) %>%
  summarize(nobs = n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from= group, values_from = nobs)

dta2 <- dta %>%
  group_by(year)%>%
  summarize(total_nobs_per_year = n())

table <- merge(dta1, dta2, by="year")

table
```

My desired table would look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use basic R function `rowSums` starting from second column, like this:

```
dta1$total_nobs_per_year<-rowSums(dta1[2:ncol(dta1)])
dta1
# A tibble: 2 x 9
# Groups:   year [2]
   year   `0`   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6` total_nobs_per_year
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>               <dbl>
1  2014   738   711   712   709   656   750   724                5000
2  2015   723   711   767   731   659   745   664                5000
```

Answer (score 1):

By definition your `total_nobs_per_year` will be the sum of the rows of `dta1` without the first column. You can use

```
dta1 %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(total_nobs_per_year = rowSums(dta1[-1]))
```

Which produces

```
# A tibble: 2 x 9
   year   `0`   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6` total_nobs_per_year
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>               <dbl>
1  2014   683   699   722   731   701   712   752                5000
2  2015   704   689   734   706   726   709   732                5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your data frame is in a tidy (long) format to begin with, you can also calculate the sum before you pivot, removing the need for two tables. Just use `mutate` instead of `summarise` to preserve all the rows:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

year <- rep(2014:2015, length.out = 10000)
group <- sample(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
value <- sample(10000, replace = T)
dta <- data.frame(year = year, group = group, value = value)


dta %>%
  group_by(year, group) %>%
  summarise(nobs = n(), .groups = "drop_last") %>%
  mutate(total_nobs_per_year = sum(nobs)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = nobs)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 9
#> # Groups:   year [2]
#>    year total_nobs_per_year   `0`   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`
#>   <int>               <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1  2014                5000   751   745   701   690   716   683   714
#> 2  2015                5000   741   737   706   632   694   746   744
```

This works because calculations in `mutate()` are also done by group (like `summarise`). It's useful if you want to add a summary column without collapsing the groups.